# nil_class when using partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-2

I have the following code:

**new.html.erb**

```
<% form_for @car,:html => {:name => 'car_form'}  do |f| %>
  <% time_created = Time.new %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :CAR_DATE_CREATED, :value => time_created %>
  <%= render :partial => "car_partial", :locals => {:object => @car } %>
  <%= f.submit 'Create'  %> 
<% end %>
```

**_car_partial.html.erb**

```
<% fields_for @car do |f| %>
  Origin: <%= f.select(:ORIGIN_TYPE,
            [['Origin X', 'X'],
            ['Origin Y', 'Y'],
            ['Other origin', 'Other']
            ],{:prompt => "Please select"}  
            ) %>


  <%= observe_field("car_ORIGIN_TYPE", :frequency => 2,
                      :url => { :controller => 'car',
                      :action => :display_other_origin },
                      :with => "'id='+value") %>



  <span id="otherOrigin" > </span>

<% end %>
```

**controller code**

```
def display_other_origin
    origin = params[:id]
end
```

**display_other_origin.rjs**

```
   if params[:id] == "Other"
      page['otherOrigin'].replace_html :partial => 'car/other_origin_type', :locals => {:car => @car }
    else
      page.replace_html :otherOrigin, ''
    end
```

**_other_origin_type.html.erb**

```
<% fields_for @car do |f| %>
If other, please state: <%= f.text_field :ORIGIN_TYPE, :size => 20%>
<% end %>
```

If user selects 'Other origin', the partial is displayed correctly but when i do `<view source>`,

```
Origin: <select id="car_ORIGIN_TYPE" name="car[ORIGIN_TYPE]">
        <option value="X">Origin X</option>
        <option value="Y">Origin Y</option>x
        <option value="Other">Other origin</option>
        </select>

<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
new Form.Element.Observer('car_ORIGIN_TYPE', 2, function(element, value) {new Ajax.Request('/cars/display_other_origin', {asynchronous:true, evalScripts:true, parameters:'id='+value + '&authenticity_token=' + encodeURIComponent('+MtiIQj/KfX2huaetD1E7W7f2pu/HC2d31BhCPjcmlQ=')})})
//]]>
</script>

<span id="otherOrigin">
If other, please state: <input id="nil_class_ORIGIN_TYPE" name="nil_class[ORIGIN_TYPE]" size="20" type="text">
</span>
```

nil_class is displayed instead of 'car'.

Any help???

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your controller action `display_other_origin` is not setting the @car variable - so it is nil when used in the display_other_origin.rjs file.

Basically, in your observe_field method you need to also set a parameter for the car id. For example:

```
<%= observe_field("car_ORIGIN_TYPE", :frequency => 2,
                  :url => { :controller => 'car',
                  :action => :display_other_origin },
                  :with => "'id='+value+'&car_id='#{@car.id}") %>
```

Then you can do `@car = Car.find(param[:car_id])` in `display_other_origin`

...although I should note that convention states that params[:id] - when passed to the CarsController - should be the car id, and your origin should be params[:origin]